# Error during installation of Joomla extension

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to install the Jumi extension in my Joomla 1.5.22 installation. I've downloaded the zip from Jumis homepage, , and followed [this](http://edo.webmaster.am/jumi/installation-in-j1.5) guide, but it gives me this error:

```
JFolder::create: Could not create directory
Warning! Failed to move file.
```

Under Help->System info->Directory Permissions all directories have "writable" in green except .../logs and .../tmp. I've checked in my ftp client and they both have access rights 777 (what should they really have?) so they should be writable but they are still marked Unwritable.

How do I make them writable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Directory Permissions listing will only tell you if the permissions are set properly, it does not necessarily mean that the extension install will work. Assuming that your temp directory path is correct, the next place to look is the FTP layer. If your server is not set up to run PHP in CGI mode, then you have to enable the FTP layer so that Joomla can write to the file system.

Also, UPDATE YOUR SOFTWARE! Joomla 1.5.9 is almost 2 years old!! You need to update to 1.5.22 ASAP. I would actually do that before messing with this error, it's entirely possible you are dealing with an old bug that has since been squashed.

Comment: oh, alright. I'll begin by upgrading then. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path to your Joomla website is incorrect
Check Global Configuration 
1) System tab : Make sure the "Path to Log folder" is correct
2) Server tab : Make sure the "Path to Temp-folder" is correct
3) Server tab : Make sure the "FTP Settings" are correct

Comment: Turns out it was some kind of link error in my file system, my web host fixed it but thanks anyway :)